# How to find what mysql query consuming more cpu resources?

Tags: mysql, resources, magento-1.9, cpu-usage, vps

I am using VPS server, CPU resources always showing 99%, how to find what mysql query consuming more cpu resources.

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all you should ssh into the server Then to check the high processing queries:

Connect `mysql -u root -p`
Type    `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` You could also use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see the full queries.

This would show all the queries running at that time.

**Second:** You should enable [Slow queries log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html) and examine it.Make sure you don't have any queries locking up key tables for too long.

**Third :** You should check your mysql users and make sure that nobody is accessing it remotely.

**Last:** Enable default magento profiler and examine slow processes.
In order to enable it go to:

`System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Profiler > Yes`

Then Open your root `index.php` file of your Magento installation then look for commented `Varien_Profiler::enable();` part and uncomment it.

If you want to enable sql profiling add `<profiler>true</profiler>` to `app/etc/local.xml`

Example:

```
<resources>
 <db>
  <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
 </db>
 <default_setup>
  <connection>
   <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
   <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
   <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
   <dbname><![CDATA[magento_1_8_1_0]]></dbname>
   <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
   <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
   <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
   <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
   <active>1</active>
   <profiler>true</profiler>
  </connection>
 </default_setup>
</resources>
```

You could even profile individual codes by adding

```
//First, enable the profiler
Varien_Profiler::enable();

//Second, start the profiler with a unique label

Varien_Profiler::start('LabelForCodeFragmentToProfile');

///... here some code we like to get statistics for

//next, stop your profiler with the same label
Varien_Profiler::stop('LabelForCodeFragmentToProfile');

//Last, disable your profiler
Varien_Profiler::disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below url

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33c7521f-7ed4-4574-82dd-aeb2f32111c5/find-high-cpu-query?forum=sqldatabaseengine

I believe this should resolve your query.

Comment: I am using MySQL, how can i find it? @Abhinaw

Comment: From SSH login, consider using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; another valuable resource is the SLOW QUERY LOG.  Consider my.cnf the following, A) slow_query_log=1  B) min_examined_row_limit=1  C) long_query_time=2 (seconds)   To determine if you have had any SLOW QUERIES since startup, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'slow_queries'; anytime.  If performance_schema is ON, you have many ways to find 'slow' events.